# Laravel ecommerce dynamic product filtering

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, e-commerce

I have this huge problem that I can't find a workaround. I'm building an e-commerce app with Laravel and it's essential to build a good filtering system for products. I have `products` and `attributes` table with a many-to-many relation. Pivot table `product_attribute` has additional `value` (if the `attribute` is color, `value` would be **red** for example) column. When entered to the shop page there is a sidebar with the filtering options. The only option I can show there is **brand** since it's a one-to-many relation with the product table. What's the right way to show these attributes. As I mentioned attributes should be dynamic to the products on the page. Different products in different categories (bikes, clothes, balls, pool tables) may have different attributes.

```
public function show($slug){

  // Get products with attributes for specic 
  $category = Category::with('products')->where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();

  // Collect brand ids
  $b_ids = array_filter($category->products->pluck('brand_id')->toArray());

  //Get brands to show in the filtering options
  $brands = Brand::whereIn('id',$b_ids)->get();

  $attributes = ?

  return view('front.shop', compact('category','brands', 'attributes'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager load attributes with products -  Category::with('products.attributes')

```php
public function show($slug){

  // Get products with attributes for specic 
  $category = Category::with('products.attributes')->where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();

  // Collect brand ids
  $b_ids = array_filter($category->products->pluck('brand_id')->toArray());

  //Get brands to show in the filtering options
  $brands = Brand::whereIn('id',$b_ids)->get();

 

  return view('front.shop', compact('category','brands'));
}
```

Then in the view attributes can be accessed via the product

> that's not what I want. It just gives me the value. I want attribute name to be displayed at the top (for example COLOR) and values (Red, Blue, etc) at the bottom next to a checkbox for the user to filter

Assuming you are storing all possible values for an attributes as options

```
// ...

@foreach($categories as $category)
   @foreach($category->products as $product)
        @include('attribute-options', ['attributes' => $product->attributes])
    @endforeach
@endforeach

// ...
```

Extract attributes display for a product to a partial - **attribute-options.blade.php**

```
@foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    <h3>{{ $attribute->name }}
    <ul>
        @foreach($attribute->options as $option)
            <li>
                <label for="{{$attribute->name}}-{{$option}}">{{ $option }}
                    <input 
                      type="radio" 
                      value="{{$option}}"
                      id="{{$attribute->name}}-{{$option}}"
                      name="{{$attribute->name}}-{{$option}}"
                    />
                </label>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: that's not what I want. It just gives me the value. I want attribute name to be displayed at the top (for example COLOR) and values (Red, Blue, etc) at the bottom next to a checkbox for the user to filter

Comment: @Mirzəyevİsmayıl Have updated answer in response to your above comment

Comment: This gives duplicates like there are 3 color sections at the filter.